# Is it prohibited to begin() the same transaction after committing it (transaction reuse )?

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I have this two method in my Database helper class.

```
public static void beginTransaction()
{
    if(transaction==null)
    {
        transaction=session.beginTransaction();
    }
    else
    {
        transaction.begin(); //this one
    }
}

public static void commitTransaction()
{
    try {
            transaction.commit();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        if(transaction!=null)
            transaction.rollback();

        closeSession();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

}
```

The problem is when `commitTransaction()` is called after one operation and then `beginTransaction()` called again for another operation it throws **`transaction instance is no longer valid`** exception. And stackTrace indicating to `transaction.begin();` operation .

**So, Is it prohibited to begin() the same transaction after committing it.?**
Or
I am doing it in the wrong way?

Note: `transaction` `session`  `closeSession()` they are my class variables and method

Comment: Isn't that exactly what the exception is telling you? Yes, it's prohibited.

Comment: then should i make the transaction `null` after  the `commit`  and remove the else statement  ? @JBNizet

Comment: You should not have a static transaction variable in the first place. That will make it impossible to have two concurrent transactions. Read http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#transactions-demarcation-nonmanaged for correct examples of code using hibernate transactions. Or better, use EJBs or Spring, and use declarative transactions.

Comment: so does it mean (in a nutshell )I should not handle transaction from the database helper class at all  for better reason ? please for give me I am not that good at this  @JBNizet

Comment: No, you shouldn't. Keep the transaction in a **local** variable, or use getCurrentSession().getTransaction() as explained in the link I gave you. Keeping the session in a static variable should not be done either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the ideal way to handle transactions, but if you insist, you might need to change your methods as follows

```
public static Transaction beginTransaction()
{

     return   session.beginTransaction();

}

public static void commitTransaction(Transaction transaction)
{
    try {
            transaction.commit();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        if(transaction!=null)
            transaction.rollback();

        closeSession();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

}
```

And this is how you need to call them

```
 Transaction tx = beginTransaction();
 //Do your stuff
 closeTransaction(tx)
```

**[Updated]**
Best way to handle transactions is Aspect Oriented Programming. If you are using spring, then you can make spring do all the hardwork of managing transaction. If you want to manage transactions on your own, the following url will give you an idea [Transactions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-demarcation). The reference that i have given you is transaction with respect to hibernate but with JDBC things wont change much.

Comment: Best way to handle transactions is Aspect Oriented Programming, if you are using spring, then you can make spring do all the hardwork of managing transaction. If you want to manage transactions on your own the following url will give you an idea [Transactions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-demarcation). The reference that i have given you is transaction with respect to hibernate but with JDBC things wont change much.